# How to dump array var to blob

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Would really appreciate some assistance / pointers with what has to be a very common and probably simple situation, but just does not seem to be obvious to me.

Consider the situation below:
[image]

All I am doing is reading some data in from a blob - works fine.

Then, using a json parse to get the dynamic tags/labels to work with.

Then I am appending the 'name' values into a variable of name: 'myArr' of type array which I initialised a step or two earlier.

When I run I can inspect the contents of 'myArr' and all the names are in there. So far so good.

Now.. how can I write the contents of 'myArr' into a blob or out to a data lake? When I add a create blob activity there is no way to select the 'myArr' variable as the content. I am messing around with another foreach control activity, but it just gets messy and doesn't work.

There has to be a simple/elegant way to push that array variable into a blob?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below works ? If still have any problem or misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Blob content" input box requires a file content but not a array variable, so you need to do some operation on "myArr". You can use "Parse JSON" action to parse the "myArr" and then you can select the "**Body**" from "Parse JSON" action into the "Blob content" input box, shown as below screenshot:

[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thak you very much. It never occurred to me to parse myArr; using your suggestion I was able to persuade the data into the right place - thank you.

As an aside, I have to say that as wonderful as Logic Apps are, I'm struggling to get the functionality I really want. I absolutely detest having to push things through for-each and re-parsing. 

Would be nice if there were some way to just let us interact witht the json using, for example, jsonpath.